# How long will Google take to index our site correctly after cleaning up a pharmaceutical hack?

Tags: google, googlebot, hacked-site

I help make edits to a hockey association website. It was recently hacked and now in Google search it shows pharmaceutical info for titles and page info, and then takes it to a pharmaceutical site, or should say did. I was able to locate the .php file that was redirecting everything.

However, the problem still remaining is that Google is listing our pages in the search engine as being pharmaceutical related. I only took care of this about an hour ago. Will this still list incorrectly until Google re indexes the site again?

Is there more than simply removing a PHP file and correcting .htaccess which was telling it to go to that PHP file? Is there a way to speed up the re-indexing?

Comment: You have two problems. One, how your site got hacked. Removing the php file is not enough. You have to figure out how your site was compromised in the first place. If you are using a CMS, then likely your software, theme, or one of the plug-ins has a vulnerability. You can check your software against this database: https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search?execution=e2s1 Update all software and replace anything that cannot be updated. Update all passwords immediately! Cheers!!

Comment: After that, then it will take time for Google to reindex your site and for it to regain the rank that it should have. Do not be surprised if it takes a couple of months.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen to clients, but it sounds like your site is not listed with Google Webmaster Tools.

The reason being, usually you get notified through their Google Webmaster Tools console and by email, stating all the reasons and pages that contain the malware. There will also be a button to "request for review" which you do after the site has been cleaned.

On average, it takes about a week, though they say 2-3 weeks.

Learn more: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/docs/request_review

Mind you, If the malware is not fixed quickly, they will add "This site may be hacked" in the SERP content and then blacklisted, if still not corrected.

[image]

> Is there more than simply removing a PHP file and correcting .htaccess

**Yes and No: Every hack is different**

If you do not know how to harden the site or the site requires upgrades the client does not want to pay for, then you may want to bring up options like a firewall or malware and security scans / removal services.

You can test your site here for free "advanced" basic scans and outdated plugins etc.
https://sitecheck.sucuri.net//

Comment: The site was already being listed in google as "this site might be hacked".  When I check the site at https://sitecheck.sucuri.net// it does not pick up any malware.  Really says that there is low risk for all items.  Am I maybe using the sitecheck incorrectly.  I am just putting the main page into the url?

Comment: That is how it works. Follow the link above about "request a review". Did you see the price for the scan and malware removal? It is good to have if you do not plan on hardening/securing the site. The also have firewalls which basically is a remote mirror hosting of your site and ultimately they never have the ability to hack your real site. I have a few clients using sucuri.

Comment: Ok thanks very much for the info!  I think Godaddy was offering to sell the sucuri service also.  This is for a hockey association and need to get it approved by our board.

Comment: You are welcome, and I believe you are thinking of SiteLock? Which their basic plan only scans and does not actually remove malware. Sucuri checks your site, I think 2 times a day. You connect them via S/FTP and if somethings happens, they immediately remedy the problem.